# Linked Set ADT implementation troubles

Tags: c++, c++11

My assignment is to make and ADT for a Set that uses linked lists. I have working methods for the ADT except for one called the "difference." This method should return a new set that contains the strings that the called upon Set and the argument Set don't have in common.

Ex.) Set 1 contains (one, two, three)

Set 2 contains (two, three)

The function should return a Set containing (one)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks much!

LinkedSet header:

```
 *
 *  @course CS1521
 *  @section 8
 *  @term Spring 2020
 *
 *  Header file for a linked implementation of the ADT set.
 *
 *  @date 20 Feb 2020*/
#ifndef LINKED_SET_
#define LINKED_SET_

#include <vector>

#include "SetInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

/** @class LinkedBag LinkedBag.h "LinkedBag.h"
 *
 *  Specification of a pointer-based ADT bag. */
template <typename ItemType>
class LinkedSet : public SetInterface<ItemType> {
 private:
  using NodePtr = Node<ItemType>*;

  /** Pointer to first node. */
  NodePtr headPtr = nullptr;

  /** Number of items in this bag. */
  int itemCount = 0;

  /** Gets a pointer to the node containing the target in this bag.
   *
   * @pre None.
   *
   * @post None.
   *
   * @param target The ItemType value to find.
   *
   * @return A pointer to the node that contains the given target or
   *         nullptr if the bag does not contain the target. */
  NodePtr getPointerTo(const ItemType& target) const;

 public:
  /** Default constructor. */
  LinkedSet() = default;

  /** Copy constructor. */
  LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& aBag);

  virtual ~LinkedSet();

  virtual int getCurrentSize() const;

  virtual bool isEmpty() const;

  virtual bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);

  virtual bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);

  virtual void clear();

  virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

  virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;

  virtual LinkedSet<ItemType> difference(LinkedSet<ItemType>& set) const;

  virtual std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
};

#include "LinkedSet.cpp"

#endif
```

Linked Set C++:

```
 *
 *  @course CS1521
 *  @section 8
 *  @term Spring 2020
 *
 *  Implementation file for the class LinkedSet.
 *
 *  @date 20 Feb 2020*/

#include <vector>

template <typename ItemType>
LinkedSet<ItemType>::LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& aSet) {

  itemCount = aSet.itemCount;

  // If aSet.headPtr is not pointing at a node:
  if (!aSet.headPtr) { // aSet.headPtr == nullptr (!nullptr == true)
    headPtr = nullptr;
  }
  else {
    NodePtr origChainPtr(aSet.headPtr);

    headPtr = new Node<ItemType>(origChainPtr->getItem() );

    NodePtr newChainPtr(headPtr);

    origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();

    while (origChainPtr) { // while (origChainPtr != nullptr) {
      newChainPtr->setNext(new Node<ItemType>(origChainPtr->getItem()) );

      newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();
      origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
    }
  }
}

template <typename ItemType>
LinkedSet<ItemType>::~LinkedSet() {

  clear();
}

template <typename ItemType>
int LinkedSet<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const {

  return itemCount;
}

template <typename ItemType>
bool LinkedSet<ItemType>::isEmpty() const {

  return itemCount == 0;
}

template <typename ItemType>
bool LinkedSet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry) {
  if (getPointerTo(newEntry) == nullptr)
        {
          headPtr = new Node<ItemType>(newEntry, headPtr);
          ++itemCount;
          return true;
        }
}

template <typename ItemType>
bool LinkedSet<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry) {

  NodePtr entryNodePtr(getPointerTo(anEntry) );

  // If entryNodePtr is pointing at a node:
  if (entryNodePtr) { // entryNodePtr != nullptr (nullptr == false)
    entryNodePtr->setItem(headPtr->getItem() );

    NodePtr nodeToDeletePtr(headPtr);

    headPtr = headPtr->getNext();

    delete nodeToDeletePtr;

    --itemCount;
  }

  return static_cast<bool>(entryNodePtr);
}

template <typename ItemType>
Node<ItemType>* LinkedSet<ItemType>::getPointerTo(const ItemType& target) const {

  NodePtr curPtr(headPtr);

  while (curPtr) { // curPtr != nullptr
    if (curPtr->getItem() == target) {
      return curPtr;
    }

    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
  }

  return curPtr; // nullptr
}

template <typename ItemType>
void LinkedSet<ItemType>::clear() {

  NodePtr nodeToDeletePtr(headPtr);

  while (headPtr) { // headPtr != nullptr
    headPtr = headPtr->getNext();

    delete nodeToDeletePtr;

    nodeToDeletePtr = headPtr;
  }
  // Note that headPtr == nodeToDeletePtr == nullptr
  itemCount = 0;
}

template <typename ItemType>
bool LinkedSet<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const {

  return static_cast<bool>(getPointerTo(anEntry) ); // ... != nullptr;
}

template <typename ItemType>
int LinkedSet<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const {

  int frequency(0);

  NodePtr curPtr(headPtr);

  while (curPtr)
    { // != nullptr
    if (curPtr->getItem() == anEntry) {
      ++frequency;
    }

    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    }

  return frequency;
}

template <typename ItemType>
LinkedSet<ItemType> LinkedSet<ItemType>::difference(LinkedSet<ItemType>& set) const{
  LinkedSet<ItemType> newSet;
  NodePtr curPtr(headPtr);
  while (curPtr)
    {
      if (set.getPointerTo(curPtr) != getPointerTo(curPtr))
        {
          newSet.add(curPtr);
        }
      curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
    }
    return newSet;
    }

template <typename ItemType>
std::vector<ItemType> LinkedSet<ItemType>::toVector() const {

  std::vector<ItemType> SetContents;

  NodePtr curPtr(headPtr);

  while (curPtr) { // != nullptr
    SetContents.push_back(curPtr->getItem() );

    curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
  }

  return SetContents;
}
```

Comment: FYI, I have removed the C tag. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: `#include "LinkedSet.cpp"` is a bad idea. Many development tools will see that cpp and compile it, leading to problems with all of the files that also included it. Looks like you can get away with it because LinkedSet.cpp is 100% template, but that can easily change. Rename the file to something like LinkedSet.hpp and you can avoid future problems.

Comment: Many unknowns in this question. Incomplete code and no clearly defined question.